Understanding Bank Conflicts in CUDA Shared Memory with 2D Arrays
I'm working with CUDA and have implemented a 2D array in shared memory, but I'm encountering bank conflicts that I'm struggling to understand. Here's my setup:
define N 10

__shared__ float ms[N][32];
__shared__ float is[N][32];
__shared__ float ds[N][32];

I launch my kernel with a grid and block configuration of <<<960, 32>>>. During kernel initialization, I set the values of the arrays to zero as follows:
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    ms[i][threadIdx.x] = 0.0f;
    is[i][threadIdx.x] = 0.0f;
    ds[i][threadIdx.x] = 0.0f;
}

However, nsight Compute reports a bank conflict of 10 ways, indicated by l1_conflicts_shared_nway. I'm not sure why this is happening, as I thought my access pattern would avoid such conflicts.
Could someone explain why I might be inducing bank conflicts with this code? I'd appreciate any insights into how I can optimize my shared memory usage to mitigate these conflicts.
Thank you in advance for your help!
I have verified that the 2D array in shared memory is organized in row-major order, which typically helps in avoiding bank conflicts due to its sequential memory access pattern. However, despite this arrangement, I am still encountering bank conflicts. This is puzzling because the row-major layout is expected to minimize such issues.

I don't see any bank conflicts if I make an otherwise empty kernel. However, I have to change the type to volatile float so that the store is not eliminated. Please provide a minimal, reproducible example

There are no bank conflicts for the code you have shown.  Contrary to what you might think by looking at metric names, nsight compute does not reliably report shared memory bank conflicts via metrics.  It requires analysis: There is not currently a hardware counter that only counts bank conflicts.   Of course, if the code you are actually running differs meaningfully from what you have shown, then its possible that you do have bank conflicts.

Thank you, after examining the SASS code, I've concluded that the problem might not be due to a banking conflict but could be the result of unloop.
